# Download Google Cloud Bucket to Specific Folder on Local Machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to download an entire bucket to my local machine.

I'm aware that the command to do this is:

```
gsutil -m cp -r \ "gs://bucket_name/folder_name/" \ .
```

However, I'd like to specify exactly where this gets downloaded on my machine due to storage limitations.

Can anyone share any advice regarding this?

Thanks in advance,

Tommy

Answer (score 1):

You can place your download files where you want to put by adding a destination url value to the last parameter of the `gsutil cp` command you are using, for example:

```
gsutil -m cp -r "gs://bucket_name" "D:\destination_folder"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering this.

I tried doing the above however I constantly get "[Errno 28] No space left on device."

The strange thing is however I have more than enough storage available on my computer.

Do you have any ideas how I can work around this?

Comment: No worries, I was able to figure it out - didn't realize I had to run the GC SDK locally.